# How do I remove this header from my inbox in Outlook on OS X?

Tags: mac, microsoft-outlook

At the top of my inbox, I see the following in Outlook:

[image]

How can I get rid of this thing? It takes up unnecessary space and is distracting.

Comment: Just to clarify -- which version of Outlook is in question?

Comment: Version 15.21.1.